# Can't run a container with a custom entrypoint script | Quarkus Jib

Tags: quarkus, jib

I'm trying to run my application on AKS with a custom entrypoint script but I received an error:

```
Error: failed to create containerd task: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/docker/run-java.sh": permission denied: unknown
```

Based on documentation I added entries to the application.properties

```
quarkus.jib.jvm-entrypoint=/docker/run-java.sh 
quarkus.jib.environment-variables."JAVA_APP_DIR"=/work
```

My custom entrypoint script is located in src/main/jib/docker/

In the Maven Jib plugin is an option to setup permission to extra directories but I don't see it in Quarkus extension for Jib.

Comment: Can you verify that the problem also occurs when building and running the image locally? If so: we could remove the `azure-aks` tag.

Comment: Is `run-java.sh` executable?

Comment: @Turing85 yes sure, I will check it

Comment: @geoand should be, probably this is an issue. During the building process run-java.sh should get the right permissions to execute the script.

Comment: You can check whether or not it's executable using https://github.com/wagoodman/dive

Comment: Assuming that the script is there (verify with `dive` as suggested by @geoand) and the issue is that it doesn't have executable permission bit set, a workaround would be `quarkus.jib.jvm-entrypoint=/bin/sh,/docker/run-java.sh` (also assuming `/bin/sh` exists).

Comment: run-java.sh is unexecutable (464). @ChanseokOh thanks for the hint, I will check it

Answer (score 3):

Having `/bin/sh` to run my script solved my issue.

```
quarkus.jib.jvm-entrypoint=/bin/sh,/docker/run-java.sh
```